# How to write object mapper to DE serialize the response json date to xmlgregoriancalendar date with springboot and jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper, xmlgregoriancalendar

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` from String "1983-02-09T00:00:00:000Z": not a valid textual representation, problem: 1983-02-09T00:00:00:000Z; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` from String "1983-02-09T00:00:00:000Z": not a valid textual representation, problem: 1983-02-09T00:00:00:000Z
"dateOfExipre" xml type xsd field as @XmlSchemaType(name = "date") protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateOfExipire; its xsd type class, not able to change this

Comment: How have you declared this property in the POJO?

Comment: @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateOfExipire; its xsd type class, not able to change this

Comment: Why do you want an `XMLGregorianCalendar`? That’s an old class. I recommend you use `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`. Those two classes are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: It’s not my home field, so just guessing: would `@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")` imply that only the date should be in the string, so just `1983-02-09`?